# Magento 2 : Import product from csv configurable product error

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, error, import, csv

I am working on `Magento 2.1.3` product import with CSV.

I am getting a error while using following CSV file.

[download csv](http://www.wikiupload.com/BVPM4Y75IDBAI7S)

Error is "**General system exception happened**"

Comment: Do you receive any other validation errors?

Answer (score 1):

I imported your file on my Magento 2 system and had a couple data incompatibility issues, but once I fixed those, I started digging into the code for you and here's the error that is being thrown:

```
Notice: Undefined index: required in /var/www/sites/classic_parts/docs/vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Import/Product/Option.php on line 1114
```

After digging further, I realized that it's because you don't have a `store_view_code` for the product. Magento 2 requires a store view code when importing product options.

Also, your option data seems to be missing a `name` value, which Magento 2 will look for. This also causes errors. Also, after you fix that, you will likely encounter another error because you don't have a `required` value specified on the option, so you should set that as well.

Please let me know if you have any other questions!